# Какие языки необходимы для создания функции сортировки товара помимо html и css?

Tags: сортировка

Какие языки необходимы для создания функции сортировки товара помимо html и css?

Comment: php или javascript

Comment: да и пхп не очень нужен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой язык, на котором написан движок магазина. Как раз вместо html и css, которые для этой цели не подходят.

А вообще сортировка задаётся на уровне формирования запроса к базе данных посредством конструкции [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp), это самый правильный путь. Подробнее об этом можете прочитать, например, [по ссылке](https://myrusakov.ru/sql-sort.html).

**UPD**. Если перед вами стоит вопрос о выборе языка для изучения и последующего коммерческого веб-программирования, то лично мое мнение: относительно простой для изучения язык - это php. Для интерфейсов понадобится знать javascript. Быстрый старт с javascript - это изучение [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: 118_64, но html, css, javascript - это то, что понадобится на клиентской части, а уж php, mysql на серверной - разве не так?

Comment: Одну и ту же задачу можно решить несколькими способами. Безусловно, на клиенте можно сортировать список товаров с помощью javascript. Но это стоит делать разве что в качестве функционала пользовательского интерфейса. Чаще же возможность сортировки реализуется не просто на уровне языка, на котором написан back end (серверная часть), например, php, но на уровне формирования запроса к базе данных (sql).

Comment: По поводу jQuery не соглашусь. В своё время это была реально очень нужная библиотека, но при развитии JavaScript в него добавлялиь лучше идеи и подходы с разных библиотек, в том числе и с JQuery много взяли. И в современным JavaScript есть большая часть того что есть в jQuery и по сути надобность в ней отпала, так как всё или почти всё есть уже в JavaScript из коробки.

Comment: Если мы обсуждаем возможности функционала, то я с вами полностью согласен. Если мы обсуждаем простоту изучения и использования новичком, то jQuery быстрее и проще в обучении и использовании. Не фундаментальней, нет. Быстрее и проще.

Answer (score 1):

Товар на клиент (браузер) в 99% попадает с сервера. Сортировка соответсвенно происходит на сервере в большинстве случаев. HTML и CSS это браузерные технологии, и сама сортировка в их задачу не входит, они отвечают чисто за отображение (инструкции для отображения). Так что сортировка это вопрос сервера, и это может быть любой серверный язык C#, PHP, Node.Js...

Comment: А какой бы Вы посоветовали для новичка?

Comment: Я бы почитал про разные языки для начала, какой больше понравится, какой отзовётся внутри. У каждого языка есть свои сильные и слабые стороны.

Comment: Наиболее популярные языки на которых может работать сайт это C#, PHP, Python, Node.JS, Java если что забыл думаю ребята подскажут.